# how to determine website's sessions on Power BI using Google Analytics (GA) data

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi

I tried addressing this question on the Power BI community forum, which pointed me to the GA forum,
but even there no help whatsoever. Below my original question:

I am using Power BI to get GA data on a given website.

My task is to determine the number of sessions which start from the home page and end on

- the homepage, without further navigation
- a specific URL
- any other page within the website

but also the number of session which start from a specific landing page and end on

- the specific URL
- any other page within the website

If I want to calculate averages, it would be convenient to determine the total amount of sessions too.

I tried gathering all information which sounded relevant from GA by creating a Power BI query and
calling the following metrics and dimensions:

- *landing page*
- *exit page*
- *exits*
- *unique pagesviews*
- *entrances*
- *pages/session*

However the values I am getting are quite chaotic or misleading and the explanations provided on
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/#ga:entrances
are now always straightforward to the lay person.

I have some ETL experience on Power Query and data analysis with DAX on Power BI,
but I'm quite lost with GA data and its jargon.

Could someone share some advice with me or point me in the right (search) direction? Thank you